# Summing values across multiple spreadsheets based on date

Tags: google-sheets, sum

I'm trying to sum values across multiple Google Sheet spreadsheets (workbooks) that are grouped by dates. For example, I want to sum all the Delta values for March 2, 2020 across multiple spreadsheets and each spreadsheet will have 0 or more values for that date.

Here's an example with 2 spreadsheets:

Spreadsheet 1:

```
Date        Start   Stop    Delta
Mon 02Mar20 16:51   16:56   0:05
Mon 02Mar20 16:56   17:00   0:03
Tue 03Mar20 18:45   18:49   0:03
Tue 03Mar20 19:04   19:06   0:01
```

Spreadsheet 2:

```
Date        Start   Stop    Delta
Mon 02Mar20 8:38    8:49    0:11
Tue 03Mar20 4:47    4:50    0:03
Tue 03Mar20 17:42   17:55   0:13
Tue 03Mar20 17:58   18:45   0:47
Tue 03Mar20 18:53   19:03   0:10
```

I want to have a dynamic sum of the Delta columns across spreadsheets by each day in a separate spreadsheet. So here's what I would like to autogenerate. Specifically, the sum of the Delta values for Spreadsheet 1 and Spreadsheet 2 for each day (0:08, 0:11, 0:04, 1:10):

```
Date        Total   Spreadsheet 1   Spreadsheet 2
Mon 02Mar20 0:19    0:08            0:11
Tue 03Mar20 1:14    0:04            1:10
```

I tried using [IMPORTRANGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en) but I'm not sure how to make the sums dynamic for each day. I don't know ahead of time how many entries I'll have for each date in Spreadsheet 1 and 2 so I want to have a way to auto determine how many rows to sum up each day for Spreadsheet 1 and 2. I'm guessing I would need to use [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) or [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197) to filter all the imported values from IMPORTRANGE but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: What have you tried until now?

Comment: Updated question with what I tried

Comment: share a copy of your sheet (also whats your definition of "workbook"?)

Comment: I updated my question to use "spreadsheet" instead of "workbook"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made an easy dataset to be sum up. Got a Spreadsheet like this:

[image]

As you can see, the total sum values for `2nd march` would be 2 and for `3rd March` would be 20.

In a different Spreadsheet, got my dashboard:

[image]

The formula I've used in B2 is:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rnap9LJQJaqriiJLSsF7EWQLwBUiNviktxDAMFfW0ZE";"Hoja 1!A1:A4")=$A2);IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rnap9LJQJaqriiJLSsF7EWQLwBUiNviktxDAMFfW0ZE";"Hoja 1!B1:B4"))
```

This is how it works:

1. `--(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rnap9LJQJaqriiJLSsF7EWQLwBUiNviktxDAMFfW0ZE";"Hoja 1!A1:A4")=$A2)` will compare the values of column A in Workbook 1 with the date in column A in my main dashboard. Because we've used a [double unary operator](https://exceljet.net/glossary/double-unary) this will return an array of 1 and 0 if there is a match or not (in this case, it will be an array like `{1;1;0;0}`
2. `IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rnap9LJQJaqriiJLSsF7EWQLwBUiNviktxDAMFfW0ZE";"Hoja 1!B1:B4")` will return as array the values of column B in Workbook 1, in this case it will return `{1;1;10;10}`
3. `SUMPRODUCT` will multiply both arrays and sum up the values, in this case `{1;1;0;0} * {1;1;10;10} = {1;1;0;0}` and the sum up of this final array is 2.

Same logic applied to second date, we would obtain `{0;0;1;1} * {1;1;10;10} = {0;0;10;10} -> 20`

Just add each workbook in 1 different column with same formula, and then do a normal sum up in your main dashboard to get the Grand total sum for all values in all workbooks for a specific date:

[image]

Hope this helps.

**NOTICE:** Of course, this method will work only if your dates are dates (not strings/texts) and the times in Delta are date/times too (not strings/texts)

Comment: I tried your solution but when I try and use `IMPORTRANGE` with the `=$A2` I only get back a single value instead of an array. Here's what I have: ```=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1i2k1BISjtgeCO6j0R88f5YK0qtyd5wDnG5JnzIirTi-I","Timesheet!a2:a200")=A25``` but instead of getting an array of values that match A25 (the date in the main spreadsheet), I just get back a single value of `TRUE` or `FALSE`. And it doesn't matter how many matched rows I have - it always returns a single value of `TRUE` or `FALSE`

Comment: When I add the double unary operator it just changes the `TRUE` to a `1` or the `FALSE` to a `0` but I still only have single value even when there are multiple rows in the other spreadsheet that match the date in the main spreadsheet.